# Using findOne() / findAll() in spring boot for Cassandra DB

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

During code optimization I found few areas where I was using findOne() within for loop –

```
public List<User> validateUsers(List<String> userIds) {
    List<User> validUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( String userId : userIds) {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(userId); //Network hit :: expensive call
        //Perform validations 
        ...
        //Add valid users to validUsers list
        ...
    }
    return validUsers;
}
```

Above method takes long time if I pass huge list of users to validate. [for 300 users around 5 sec.]

Then I changed above method to use findAll() and perform validations on result collection -

```
public List<User> validateUsers(List<String> userIds) {
    List<User> validUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterable<User> itr = userRepository.findAll(userIds); //Only one Network hit

    for ( User user : itr) {

        //Perform validations 
        ...
        //Add valid users to validUsers list
        ...
    }
    return validUsers;
}
```

Now for 300 users, results coming in 100 ms.
Question is: Is there any side effects of using findAll() considering the underlying structure of Cassandra? Also I am using CrudRepository. Should I use CassandraRepository?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the parameters to think of when you are attempting this.

1. How big is the users table, if you are using findAll.
2. Partition keys for the user table

As Cassandra queries are faster with the primary key fields, findOne might perform better with the large amount of data.

However, can you try

```
List<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);
```

from `org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository`

Comment: Users table can have large data. userid is the partitioned key in the table. What is the difference in findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids) [CassandraRepository] and findAll(Iterable<ID> ids) [CrudRepository]?